# Spring Cloud Consul - register another service

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-consul

I have 2 services A and B 
service A is a legecy code wrapped in jar that I cant touch .
Service B is spring boot application with Spring Cloud Consul attached .

I would like to register them both using service B , it's possible ?

*Notice*
I can achieve my goal by using https://github.com/Ecwid/consul-api project but there would be a redundency couse O would like to work with consul spring features

Comment: Both services are in the same jar ? do they have the same "base" url (hostname, port, context path) and only the service relative path differ ?

Comment: nowadays they are running in the same server under **different** context path @MichaelTecourt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way

```
@Autowired
ConsulClient consulClient;
```

and from there doing as refrenced [here](https://github.com/Ecwid/consul-api)